# MySql filtering data from insert query

Tags: mysql

I'll start by saying I'm new to MySql, at least in the level of my question. :)

I got a data logger with a high data output and I'm interested in saving the data to a database.
I've been wondering if it's possible to filter the INSERT query in the database itself, so it will save only data if certain values appear in the query.

Comment: CHECK constraint(s) on a column(s) with restriction(s), and INSERT IGNORE instead of single INSERT.

Comment: Yes. Often you can build the logic into the INSERT itself

Comment: If i recall correctly INSERT IGNORE deals only with errors. Am I correct?
Can anyone send a link for an example or a example query?

Comment: *If i recall correctly INSERT IGNORE deals only with errors.* If error occures the whole INSERT fails and none is inserted. If IGNORE added then all errors are converted to warnings, and the rows which does not cause error are inserted. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e60f60bd8f3cd5696642a11678b4818).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akina mentioned, you can use CHECK CONSTRAINT and INSERT IGNORE. However, It is better not trying to insert any problematic data, since it will slow down insert operation.

you need to filter data before insert operation. You may want to consider writing custom log shipper or if you have option you can use [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash)

Comment: *It is better not trying to insert any problematic data, since it will slow down insert operation.* As I understand OP cannot affect the input data stream. He want to save this data partially for to decrease final data array.

Comment: *since it will slow down insert operation.* I doubt. To check and eject row in memory only is faster than to write unneeded row **to disk**.

Comment: logstash does this in memory.  Also, If OP writes custom log shipper, he can discard stream data on the go (while in memory).

Comment: I.e. checking is performed nevertheless. The only economy will be the traffic to MySQL.